# UINavigation slide up transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a question about a view sliding up.
The example would be iOS's contacts app.
When you want to add a new contact, a view slides up automatically.
How do you achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check-out the Presenting a View Controller and Choosing a Transition Style section.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Hint: `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`

Answer (score -1):

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:SOMEVIEW animated:YES];

SOMEVIEW just needs to be a uiviewcontroller you created.  you're current view needs a navigation controller also.

Comment: That's incorrect. In order to maintain the same *transition style*, you do not need a UINavigationController.

Comment: it's correct if you use the line of code I posted.  You can just do [view presentModalViewcontroller: animated:], but the poster asked about 'like iOS contacts' app, which uses a navigation controller and presents a modal onto of it.  At least that what it looks like the iOS contact app does.

Comment: Yes, he did, in regards to the transition style (animation), not the actual interface.